# Constant Harmonic Mean surfaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

For surfaces embedded in $\mathbb R^3$ with principal curvatures $ \kappa_1, \kappa_2 $ we know bending/isometric mappings conserve  $ K= \kappa_1  \kappa_2 $ and  CMC  DeLaunay type minimal surfaces  conserve $ 2 H =\kappa_1 +\kappa_2 $ by a physical differential pressure.

What type of deformations are conserved with $ (1/\kappa_1 +1/\kappa_2 )?$ Is there any physical or mathematical description for this class of surfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surfaces with constant $(\tfrac{1}{\kappa_1}+\tfrac{1}{\kappa_2})$ are contained in the class of linear Weingarten surfaces, i.e., surfaces such that 
$$2aH+bK=c$$
for some  $a,b,c\in\mathbb R.$ 
These surfaces are well-studied. They are critical points
for an energy functional which contains area, enclosed volume and total mean curvature terms.
You can find many papers on this topic by a short search, for example 
"Linear Weingarten Surfaces in R3" by Galvez, Martinez and Milan, and the references therein.